# a concept question for topological vector space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $x\in U$ as interior for the set $U$ in topological vector space.

Can we show $\lambda \ne 0$ then $\lambda x\in \lambda U$ is interior for $\lambda U$?

I do as follows:

first since $x\in U$ is interior.i.e. exist $U_x = x +U_o\subset U$

Now $\lambda x + \lambda U_o  \subset \lambda U$ now we know for TVS $\lambda U_o$ is also neiborhood of origin,hence exist some neiborhood of $\lambda x $ contains in $\lambda U$ hence it's interior.

Is my proof correct?

One Corollary is if zero is interior for $U$ then zero is interior for all $nU$ correct?

Comment: YES to both. In fact $x \to \lambda x$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: o k , t h a n k s

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for topological spaces with a notion of scalar multiplication.